# Squaring both sides of an inequality: attempt to prove a general rule

Tags: inequality, proof-verification

I have attempted to produce a proof of the intuitive rule for squaring inequalities, according to which, given any two numbers *x* and *y* and regardless of their sign,

1) if |*x*| < |*y*| then $x^2<y^2$;

2) if |*x*| > |*y*| then $x^2>y^2$.

Proof for Case 1:

Let *x* and *y* being any two real numbers such that |*x*| < |*y*|.

- Multiplying both sides by |*x*| gives |*x*||*x*| < |*y*||*x*|. Hence, by the result |*a*||*b*| = |*ab*|, we have |*x*|$^2$<|*xy*|;
- Multiplying both sides by |*y*| gives |*y*||*x*| < |*y*||*y*|. Hence, by the same result, we get |*xy*|<|*y*|$^2$.

Now, merging the two inequalities we get |*x*|$^2$<|*xy*|<|*y*|$^2$, to give |*x*|$^2$<|*y*|$^2$. By the result |*a*|$^2$ = _a_$^2$ we get _x_$^2$<_y_$^2$.
This completes the proof in the first case.

Proof for Case 2:

Let *x* and *y* being any two real numbers such that |*x*| > |*y*|.

- Multiplying both sides by |*x*| gives |*x*||*x*| > |*y*||*x*|. Hence, by the result |*a*||*b*| = |*ab*|, we have |*x*|$^2$>|*xy*|;
- Multiplying both sides by |*y*| gives |*y*||*x*| > |*y*||*y*|. Hence, by the same result, we get |*xy*|>|*y*|$^2$.

Merging the two inequalities we get |*x*|$^2$>|*xy*|>|*y*|$^2$, to give |*x*|$^2$>|*y*|$^2$. By the result |*a*|$^2$ = _a_$^2$ we get _x_$^2$>_y_$^2$.
This completes the proof in the second case.

Substantially this proof (hopefully correct) follows the same path as the proof for squaring both sides of an inequality. The difference is that here we take into account only absolute values, which avoids us the tricky task of considering signs.

Any comment or suggestion to improve (or disprove!) this would be most welcome!

Comment: You don't have to prove case $2$: it's contained in case $1$ by exchanging the roles of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: I've  never seen such inefficient proof. $|x|<|y|$ means that $x^2=|x||x|<|y||x|<|y||y|=y^2$. That's it!. And you don't haev to prove 2) it is equivalent to 1) up to exchchange of symbols $x,y$.

Comment: @AlexanderVigodner; I can't see any difference between your proof and the proof of the OP excep that the OP's proof is more wordy. Or do I miss something?

Comment: @miracle173, well I am not  merging any intermediate inequalities, but may be you are right, though for me it is really too many words and relations to prove the simple fact.

Comment: Actually yes, probably too wordy and too obvious. Put this way however this may be a useful rule of thumb to decide the inequality sign after squaring simply by checking magnitudes. I have seen around many doubts about how doing this, so I hope this might provide a quick practical rule along with proof

Comment: @AlexanderVigodner The OP is using step-by-step justification for the proof based on a set of either axioms or previously proven theorems.  In many introductory real analysis or advanced calculus courses, the course begins with a rigorous approach to proving those things that we now take for granted.  The OP's approach was fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof seems correct, although a bit too complicated.

If you know that $x \mapsto x^2$ is a strictly increasing function on $\Bbb{R}_{\geq 0}$, then you immediately know that $|x| > |y|$ iff $x^2 > y^2$ for every $x,y \geq 0$ (by definition of [strictly increasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function)). To prove that, the quickest way would be to observe that $\frac{d}{dx}(x^2) = 2x \geq 0$ for $x \geq 0$, with equality only for $x=0$.

---

To keep things elementary, you could instead observe that $|x| > |y|$ implies
$$
|x||y| < |x||x| = x^2
\qquad \text{and} \qquad
|x||y| > |y||y| = y^2
$$
Putting the two together gives $|x| > |y| \Rightarrow x^2 > y^2$. Reversing the roles of $x$ and $y$ gives (1), but note that the two cases are really just the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that both inequalities follow from proving that

$\;\;\;$If $0\le a<b,$ then $a^2<b^2$; and

$\;\;\;0\le a<b\implies a^2\le ab\;$ and $\;ab<b^2\implies a^2<b^2$.

Comment: Absolutely correct! My aim however was to reflect about a general rule (perhaps obvious) to quickly determine the sign of the inequality after squaring along with proof of its truth. The proof given above considers only   the case in which 'a' and 'b' are positive, while when considering magnitudes we are not concerned abut signs